# How to implement an exchange plateform using web services

Tags: java, spring, web-services, wcf, architecture

I'm trying to figure out what's the best approach to implement an exchange platform over web services.

**Acme** company decides to implement some sort of an exchange platform with other companies (collaborators), easily configurable via a web interface (add/remove collaborators), this platform should route the requests to the appropriate company's *internal* web services (with private IP addresses and not accessible from outside) after validating the request format and of course an authorization check as well.

When **Acme** wanted to collaborate with **Dusk Motors**, they established that **Dusk Motors** would send the **Acme** company the following data :

- **Motor Model Number** : String value.
- **Specification Sheet** : *pdf* file.

---

What I have so far is this (also illustrated in the image further below) :

We would create an *.xsd file to validate this input and also generate some API-Key to identify **Dusk Motors**. This information would be stored in a DB accessible from the exchange platform's web service and the information flow would be something like this :

1. **Dusk Motors** should send data with this format :

   - **API-Key** : the collaborator's API-Key
   - **DATA** : an ***xml chunk*** conforming to the *.xsd file we created.
2. The exchange platform's webservice does the following :

   - Checks if the received data is under the format API-KEY/DATA.
   - Using the API-Key, it gets from DB the *.xsd file and the internal web server's address (destination of the request)
   - Validates the DATA chunk using the *.xsd file.
3. If all went fine, it sends the DATA chunk to the appropriate internal web server for processing (might perform business validation if needed).

The API-Key/DATA format is used in order to support adding other collaborators when needed just by simple DB configuration via a web interface.

---

#### Questions

Without insisting on any web services' protocol (SOAP, REST etc.), language (java, .NET) or technology (spring, WCF etc.) other than the fact that the possibility to send binary data is a requirement :

- Is what I have so far any good for **Acme** requirements?
- How could it be criticized in terms of security, bandwidth, software architecture etc.?
- Are there any off-the-shelf solutions I could look into as well?

Thank you very much for any help.

---

[image: information flow]